# Using QGIS Rotate Point Symbols tool when multiple point objects have same coordinates

Tags: qgis, point, symbology, coordinates

I'm using SVG symbols to display a layer which represents the location of traffic accidents.  The rotation of the symbol indicates the direction the vehicle was travelling.  The rotation angle is stored in a column of the table and the style uses this value to set the symbol rotation.  The layer also contains a column which indicates the *general* direction of travel, but it only contains one of four allowable values (North, South, East or West).  I have used this data to populate the symbol rotation column.

Now sometimes the angle needs some tweaking when the streets don't run exactly North-South.  I can edit the angle value directly, and sometimes I do that, but other times its convenient to use the **Rotate Point Symbols** tool:

[image]

**My problem** is when there are multiple accidents at the one location (typically an intersection) the  **Rotate Point Symbols** tool always rotates the top most symbol.  I can't find a way to drill down into the stack.

**I have tried** holding down various modifier keys.  I have tried selecting one of the lower objects via the attribute table, but the topmost still gets rotated.  I have style rule in the rendering order of the layer so selected objects are render on top - doesn't help.

The layer is from a third party and I would prefer not to modify the actual point objects so they don't overlap.